# How to Save the actual image path from UIImagePickerController (ipad)

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller, nsurl

I have an ImagePickerController to select an image that will serve as a background image in a drawing software.

I need to real actual path to the image selected in order to save it so I can be able to reload it on app close/open.

I've tried saving the NSURL given by the UIImagePicker delegate but it's not working.

I get the url like this in the delegate :

```
NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

I save/reload the url using NSCoding and then try to get the image like that :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
```

I only need the path in order to reload the image ... anyone has insight on this ?

### EDIT :

I'm starting to wonder if the proper way of doing this might not be to encode the uiimage itself !?

Comment: I've kinda fix the problem by encoding the UIImage data itself. It's better that way I think because if for some reason the image is deleted by the user while the app is not running....it would not be found by the coding method on startup. Now it's encoded and decodes, so data is always available. I think it's part of the ipad dev. best practices...but I didn't found the proper link about it !

Answer (score 0):

You might try [creating bookmark data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/bookmarkDataWithOptions%3aincludingResourceValuesForKeys%3arelativeToURL%3aerror%3a) and encoding that, and decoding and [restoring from bookmark data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLByResolvingBookmarkData%3aoptions%3arelativeToURL%3abookmarkDataIsStale%3aerror%3a), instead of the URL itself. (I should expect the URL object to handle this itself when being encoded and decoded, so if this solves the problem, I suggest [filing a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/).)

Also, if you get [the URL's path](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path), you can pass that to [the `imageOfContentsOfFile:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithContentsOfFile%3a), which may be able to load the image more efficiently than slurping the whole contents of the file into memory (at least for certain image file types).

Comment: The thing is that I think the URL provided by UIImagePickerController is not the "real" url to the path...You cannot load it back with that url afterward...

Comment: @oberthelot: Log the URL on output and both the URL and the image on input and see what you're getting.

Answer (score -1):

Try `+dataWithContentsOfFile:` in place of `+dataWithContentsOfURL:`. I've had better luck with that.

Comment: It's not an issue of luck. `dataWithContentsOfFile:` takes a pathname; `dataWithContentsOfURL:` takes a URL. If you have a path, you use the former; if you have a URL, you use the latter. Using the correct method for what you have will always work (assuming that the file exists/is reachable), and using the wrong method will always fail.